# $H$ field from corresponding $E$ field (antenna)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, antennas

The $E$ field at $kr >> 1$ due to a short dipole oriented in the $z$-direction and located at the origin is: $$E_0 = \frac{10^3e^{-jkr}}{r}\sin\theta\space\space(V/m)$$

Can I just solve for the H field using the phasor form of Faraday's law $\nabla\times\textbf{E} = -j\omega\mu\textbf{H} $ ? Or do I have to use the vector potential $\mu\textbf{H}=\nabla\times\textbf{A}$ ? I'm very unfamiliar with the vector potential, but it's in the antenna chapter in my EM book so I'm thinking it might be relevant here. If the first way doesn't work, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a go and you may find a surprising result.

In order for Faraday's laws to give you the exact result you would need to include the near-field terms in the E-field that you have implicitly ignored when you said $kr \gg 1$.

Applying Faraday's law to the E-field as written will give you multiple terms that will approximate the right result for $kr \gg 1$.

An easier way to get the far field approximation is to recognise that the E-field has the form of a propagating electromagnetic wave. In which case, it has the well known properties of an EM wave (I assume) in vacuum. That the E-field and H-field are perpendicular to each other and the direction of propagation, they are in phase, and that the E-field amplitude is $\mu c$ times the H-field amplitude.

If your book has derived the vector potential for the antenna, then the second method should also give the desired result (with two terms, a near field, and a far field that dominates when $kr \gg 1$).